# always No files found with or without jest.config.js before Timemachine of mac

Tags: mac

### Regression Report

1. Timemachine to a new mac
2. run jest of project

jest always not run all of my project.

### Last working version

Worked up to version:
24.8.0

Stopped working in version:
24.9.0
24.8.0
22.4.4

### To Reproduce

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

### Expected behavior

A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.
1. create `sum.js`

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
module.exports = sum;
```

2. create `sum.test.js`

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

3. modify package.json

```
{
  "name": "jest-2-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^22.4.4"
  }
}
```

4. run `npm run test`

```
macBook:~/code/jest-2-demo
chris$ ls -a
.                       node_modules            package.json            sum.test.js
..                      package-lock.json       sum.js
macBook:~/code/jest-2-demo
chris$ npm run test

> jest-2-demo@1.0.0 test /Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo
> jest

No tests found
No files found in /Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo.
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html
Pattern:  - 0 matches
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jest-2-demo@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jest-2-demo@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chris/.npm/_logs/2019-08-19T13_36_41_871Z-debug.log
```

### Link to repl or repo (highly encouraged)

Please provide either a [repl.it demo](https://repl.it/languages/jest) or a minimal repository on GitHub.

Issues without a reproduction link are likely to stall.

### Run `npx envinfo --preset jest`

Paste the results here:

```bsh
macBook:~/code/jest-2-demo
chris$ npx envinfo --preset jest
npx: 1 安裝成功，花費 1.927 秒

  System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.6
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.11.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node
    npm: 6.10.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm
  npmPackages:
    jest: ^22.4.4 => 22.4.4
```

### Debug

```
macBook:~/code/jest-2-demo
chris$ pwd
/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo
macBook:~/code/jest-2-demo
chris$ npx jest --debug
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "/var/folders/6q/6ll3np5j1ybf17dk3bs1lk0r0000gn/T/jest_dx",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globals": {},
      "haste": {
        "providesModuleNodeModules": []
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "jsx",
        "node"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": {},
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "714fc81ef39a7ce73f2603d4a0ec0ebf",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo",
      "roots": [
        "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [
        "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js"
      ],
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testRegex": "",
      "testRunner": "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "about:blank",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          "^.+\\.jsx?$",
          "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": false,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "coverageDirectory": "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo/coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "expand": false,
    "globalSetup": null,
    "globalTeardown": null,
    "listTests": false,
    "maxWorkers": 3,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "always",
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "rootDir": "/Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": null,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "22.4.4"
}
No tests found
No files found in /Users/chris/code/jest-2-demo.
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
To set up Jest, make sure a package.json file exists.
Jest Documentation: facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

Comment: `Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.` - Did you do this? Anything useful in /Users/chris/.npm/_logs/2019-08-19T13_36_41_871Z-debug.log?

Comment: Sorry, how to `Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.`? 
I run this by Jest default setup.

Comment: Go read the manual?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5829 & https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1686 & https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5123

Comment: I have seen it, it didn't help, but I have found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom options `--runTestsByPath unit-test/**.js` of cli. try it, success

```
macBook-2:~/code/jest-demo (master)
chris$ npm run test

> jest-demo@1.0.0 test /Users/chris/code/jest-demo
> jest --runTestsByPath unit-test/**.js

 PASS  unit-test/everyDataType.test.js
 PASS  unit-test/callback.test.js
 PASS  unit-test/async-await.test.js
 PASS  unit-test/mock.test.js
 PASS  unit-test/json.test.js
 PASS  unit-test/promise.test.js

Test Suites: 6 passed, 6 total
Tests:       3 skipped, 17 passed, 20 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.386s
Ran all test suites within paths "unit-test/async-await.test.js", "unit-test/callback.test.js", "unit-test/everyDataType.test.js", "unit-test/json.test.js", "unit-test/mock.test.js", "unit-test/promise.test.js".
```

### Debug

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "/private/var/folders/6q/6ll3np5j1ybf17dk3bs1lk0r0000gn/T/jest_dx",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "cwd": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo",
      "dependencyExtractor": null,
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "detectOpenHandles": false,
      "errorOnDeprecated": false,
      "filter": null,
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globalSetup": null,
      "globalTeardown": null,
      "globals": {},
      "haste": {
        "computeSha1": false,
        "providesModuleNodeModules": [],
        "throwOnModuleCollision": false
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "node"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": {},
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "bfdbd0febd5d8ac8761eaad7d35f82fc",
      "prettierPath": "prettier",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "resolver": null,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo",
      "roots": [
        "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
      "skipFilter": false,
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testRegex": [],
      "testRunner": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          "^.+\\.[jt]sx?$",
          "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": 0,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": null,
    "coverageDirectory": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo/coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": null,
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "detectOpenHandles": false,
    "errorOnDeprecated": false,
    "expand": false,
    "filter": null,
    "globalSetup": null,
    "globalTeardown": null,
    "json": false,
    "listTests": false,
    "maxConcurrency": 5,
    "maxWorkers": 3,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [
      "unit-test/async-await.test.js",
      "unit-test/callback.test.js",
      "unit-test/everyDataType.test.js",
      "unit-test/json.test.js",
      "unit-test/mock.test.js",
      "unit-test/promise.test.js"
    ],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "failure-change",
    "onlyChanged": false,
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "projects": null,
    "rootDir": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo",
    "runTestsByPath": true,
    "skipFilter": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "unit-test/async-await.test.js|unit-test/callback.test.js|unit-test/everyDataType.test.js|unit-test/json.test.js|unit-test/mock.test.js|unit-test/promise.test.js",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "testSequencer": "/Users/chris/code/jest-demo/node_modules/@jest/test-sequencer/build/index.js",
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": null,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "24.9.0"
}
```

#### diff key

- nonFlagArgs
- onlyChanged
- runTestsByPath
- testPathPattern